# Funny chess starting positions

Tags: opening, chess-variants

Recently, I found this funny position called Omicron. Are there are any other funny starting positions like this that can be used to have fun with friends?

```
[FEN "2bqkb2/1rppppr1/np4pn/p6p/P6P/NP4PN/1RPPPPR1/2BQKB2 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Did you invent this starting position? Anyway, it gives White a big advantage. Stockfish 14 on depth 22 gives 1 d4 +1.13.

Comment: no, not me? I've found this accidentaly in internet :)

Comment: @RosieF What's Stockfish's main line?  Is the point that d3(d4) and e3(e4) gain tempo by attacking the loose Nh6/Na6 ?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Stockfish 14, on my PC with a 3.2GHz quad-core Intel i5-4460 CPU, gives 1 d4 e5 2 Nb5 (Nb1 d5 3 Bxh6 Bxh3 4 dxe5) c6 (Ng4 3 e4) 3 Bxh6 cxb5 (d5 4 Ng5/Rg1/Rh2; not Bb4+? 4 c3 cxb5 5 cxb4 d5 6 Bxg7 Bxh3) 4 axb5 (e4) Nc7 (Nb4/Bb4+) 5 dxe5 (c4 d5; Bxg7 Bxg7 6 c4) Nxb5 (d5 6 exc6; Bb4+ 6 Bd2) 6 c4 (Bxg7 Bxg7) d5 7 cxb5 Bxh3 (Bb4+ 8 Bd2 Bxh3 9 Bxb4 axb4) 8 Rh2 Be6. I limited Stockfish's analysis of each ply to 60s, so different runs might give different results.

Comment: Of course there are such positions (even on CSE; recently there was one where all white officers stand *before* the pawns, amazingly the position is rather =). The latter is also the snag: for real fun such a position should be = (and for additional lulz, very unbalanced like that I quoted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of these on the internet ( [1](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/fun-with-chess/custom-positions-copetetion), [2](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/fun-with-chess/funniest-chess-positions?page=3)), though how much fun is to be had is up to those that choose to play them. Such judgements are beyond me.

I've never tried any of these. And I don't plan to.

---

A few selections.

```
[Title "Position #1"]
[FEN "rnbqqbQR/npppppPN/bp4PB/kp4PK/qp4PQ/bp4PB/npPPPPPN/rqBQQBNR w - - 0 1"]
```

Another one.

```
[Title "Position #2"]
[FEN "r2qk2r/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/R2QK2R w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

One with the Queens in jail.

```
[Title "Position #3"]
[FEN "r1b1kb1r/Pp1ppppp/qP6/Pp6/pP6/Qp6/pP1PPPPP/R1B1KB1R w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

The Kings in jail.

```
[Title "Position #4"]
[FEN "r2q1nnr/Pp1ppppp/kP6/Pp6/pP6/Kp6/pP1PPPPP/R2Q1NNR w - - 0 1"]
```

No Rooks.

```
[Title "Position #5 (~+2.6)"]
[FEN "qk6/bbb5/nnnn4/ppp5/5PPP/4NNNN/5BBB/6KQ w - - 0 1"]
```

A key challenge is finding starting positions that lead to interesting play and have close to equal evaluations. For example...

```
[Title "Position #6"]
[FEN "1k6/ppp2ppq/ppp2ppp/5ppp/PPP5/PPP2PPP/QPP2PPP/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

And simple changes?

```
[Title "Position #7 (+6.9)"]
[FEN "8/8/rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

It depends.

```
[Title "Position #8 (+0.5)"]
[FEN "8/rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Some aren't too bad.

```
[Title "Position #9 (+0.3)"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/pppppppp/1p1p1p1p/1P1P1P1P/PPPPPPPP/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
```